# How can a battery have electric potential?

Tags: voltage, batteries, field

Electric potential is the potential energy of a charged particle in a point in space relative to another point in space in an electric field, all that divided by the charge of that particle. I don't understand how it relates to the voltage in a circuit and battery? To have a potential there must have a field...

Answer (score 3):

A battery stores an electrochemcial potential.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage

Comment: Gonna add a link to the battery's "Principle of Operation": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_(electricity)#Principle_of_operation